# How to parse the response array in json in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Hi I have to parse the following response using AJAX.I have been trying it but I didnt get.

```
[{"Status":"True"},{"Data":[{"ApplicationNo":"RE09","ApplicationName":"Salim"},{"ApplicationNo":"RE13","ApplicationName":"V Damodaran"}]}]

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#btnlogin").click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
              var txtUsernameID = $("input#useridtxt").val();
             var txtPasswordID = $("input#pwdtxt").val(); 
             alert(txtUsernameID+","+txtPasswordID);

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 //data: '{"username":"' + $("input#txtusername").val() + '","password":"' + $("input#txtpassword").val() + '"}',
                 url: '',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 dataType: 'json',

                 success:
              function (url, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {




                 $.each(url.Data, function(index, item) {
                    alert(item.agentid);

                });         



                 },
                 error:
              function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(textStatus);
              }

             });

         });
     });


</script>
```

Comment: var data = eval("(" + data + ")"); // url should be data

Comment: @halex: Not really a duplicate, as this question isn't really about the parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the JSON at all, the `ajax` method does that for you when you specify `'json'` as data type.

What you get is an array with two items, and the `Data` property is in the object in the second array item, so you reach it using `url[1].Data`:

```
$.each(url[1].Data, function(index, item) {
  alert(item.agentid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in youre success function you need to parse the response to json. most browsers have a native JSON.parse() function you can use to test with

Comment: He may need JSON2.js script from here >> https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js